# Azure Cosmos DB error in creating database: The remote name could not be resolved

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm trying to make a functional basic **Azure Cosmos Database** workflow.

From my Azure account, I'm getting the **endpoint** address from the `HOST` param in the "Connection String" in "Settings", and the **key** from the "PRIMARY PASSWORD" param.

```
string EndpointUri = "https://<my-database-name>.mongo.cosmos.azure.com";
string PrimaryKey ="<my-key>";
```

then I try to create the client (following these [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/quickstart-dotnet?tabs=azure-cli%2Cwindows)):

```
CosmosClient cosmosClient = new(
    uri, 
    key, 
    new CosmosClientOptions(){ 
        ApplicationRegion = Regions.WestUS 
    }
);
database = cosmosClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(id: databaseId).Result;
```

But I keep getting and error

> The remote name could not be resolved

Am I using the **Endpoint** and **Key** wrong...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I using the Endpoint and Key wrong...?

Yes. You are using the Endpoint incorrectly.

The endpoint should be `https://<account-name>.documents.azure.com`.

Comment: this solved the error I had, nevertheless I have a different error where `Sql api is not supported for this database account`
I will explore in different place/thread probably. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using the Mongo API and using the SQL .Net SDK against it,
Here is the example to connect with [Mongo API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/connect-mongodb-account) using the [driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/quickstart-dotnet?tabs=azure-cli%2Cwindows#authenticate-the-client).

```
var client = new MongoClient(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MONGO_CONNECTION"));
```

Comment: I guess so, but I thought Cosmos should work out of the box, and not sure how to set up an entire MongoClient separately... in any case I don't want to work only locally so I'm not sure how to set up the environment variables on machines that will use the code. seems quite complex for just setting up a simple DB..

Answer (score 2):

You've mixed-n-matched protocols. Every instance of Cosmos DB has an associated protocol (SQL API, MongoDB API, etc). Your example shows you chose the MongoDB API (which has a MongoDB endpoint) with the Cosmos DB API's SDK (and that won't work). Note: When I mentioned *instance* of Cosmos DB, I mean a complete namespace (which you created), and that namespace encapsulates all of your databases and related containers, permissions, etc.

When using the MongoDB API, you need to use standard MongoDB SDKs (provided by MongoDB or by the community), and then code against it just as you would code against native MongoDB databases.

The only protocol that uses the Cosmos DB SDK is the native SQL API (which is the SDK referenced in the code in your question).

If you really wanted to use different protocols (e.g. some Cosmos DB native containers, some MongoDB containers, some Cassandra keyspaces...), you'd need to create individual instances of Cosmos DB (three instances, in this case).